# Parser for LateX generated by Mathquill

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

I'm working on a website where the user types in two expressions using Mathquill and I want to use a servlet and a computer algebra system to check if the two expressions are mathematically equivalent after performing certain simplifications. The part I have trouble with is with the parser. I already have a parser that I've used in the past but it doesn't support implicit multiplication (two or more numbers or letters next to each other without a \ in front are tried as being multiplied), operators like sine (which will always start with a \ ), and \frac{}{}. I'm not very good with context free grammars but this is the grammar I used before

A -> X|B

X->(A)|[a-z]|[0-9]

B -> B+C|C

C -> C-D|D

D-> D*E|E

E-> E/F|F

F->F^X|X

What I am looking for in this question is how I can change this context free-grammar so that it handles implicit multiplication, latex operators, and \frac{}{}. (I also need to deal with curly bracket groupings but I think I can treat that like parentheses). I know that there are already parsers in Java for latex but I want to make my own parser so that it uses my classes for AdditionExpression, etc., since my computer algebra system uses those classes. I think the process will also be simpler because I only need to parse strings from Mathquill rather than arbitrary latex code.

Comment: Does it need to be able to distinguish between, say *x* times *y* (implicit) and a variable named *xy*?

Comment: I'm assuming that there are no variables which are multiple characters

Comment: Operators can have multiple characters but they have an opening slash to distinguish them from variables

Comment: You should spell out, as precisely as possible, what you want to capture; hopefully that will make the grammar mods more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. This is what I came up with

A -> X|B

X->\operator(A)|(A)|{A}|[a-z]|[0-9] (I have a separate method that deals with expressions with multiple numbers or letters)

B -> B+C|C

C -> C-D|D

D-> [0-9]|D*E|DE|E| (to check DE I have to loop over all positions in the string and try to split the string into two pieces)

E-> \frac{E}{F}|F

F->F^X|X
What I realized that is the order of the parsing has to do with order of operations so I would still check for multiplication and division in the same places and what I called X consists of all unary operations (operations like parentheses, brackets, and operators which have only one input) and variables and letters. I have to check for numbers again in multiplication so I don't get 21=2*1

Leave a comment or a different answer if what I wrote doesn't work.